# Excel VBA macro for generating graphs from multiple tables - nested macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to generate graph automatically based on my selection. This works fine if I select one table. I have to select one table at a time to generate the graph. Is there a way I can set up a nested macro to select the worksheet and generate the individual chart for each table?

Any inputs will be appreciated. Thank you :)

macro to generate one chart

' Macro3 Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a

Sub graph()

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As ChartObject

Set rng = Selection
rng(1, 1).Clear
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add( _
    Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
    Width:=450, _
    Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
    Height:=250)

'Give chart some data
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

'Determine the chart type
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlLine

'Ensure chart has a title
cht.Chart.HasTitle = True

'Change chart's title
cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "My Graph"


'Add Legend to the Bottom
cht.Chart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)
```

End Sub

Table 1:
period BA   BC  BD  BE
20174   4.1 4.1 4.1 4.1000
20181   4.0 4.5 5.0 5.0544
20182   4.0 5.3 6.5 6.2598
20183   3.9 5.8 7.6 7.4139
20184   3.8 6.3 8.5 8.5021
20191   3.8 6.6 9.3 9.1129
20192   3.8 6.9 9.7 9.5360
20193   3.8 7.0 10.0    10.0037
20194   3.7 7.0 9.9 9.8787
20201   3.8 6.9 9.7 9.6216
20202   3.9 6.8 9.5 9.3975
20203   4.0 6.6 9.2 9.2134
20204   4.0 6.5 8.9 9.0484
20211   4.1 6.3 8.6 8.8423

Table 2:
period  CA  CC  CD  CE
20174   -5.38462    -5.3846 -5.3846 -5.3846
20181   -6.97674    4.6512  16.2791 17.5446
20182   -2.43902    29.2683 58.5366 52.6777
20183   -2.50000    28.8889 52.0000 46.6822
20184   -5.00000    18.8679 30.7692 35.8204
20191   -2.56410    13.7931 22.3684 22.9164
20192   .00000  9.5238  14.1176 12.1615
20193   .00000  6.0606  7.5269  9.7749
20194   -2.63158    1.4493  2.0619  3.5928
20201   .00000  -1.4286 -3.0000 -3.8200
20202   5.40541 -2.8571 -4.0404 -4.8709
20203   5.26316 -4.3478 -5.1546 -4.2420
20204   2.56410 -4.4118 -6.3158 -3.7151
20211   2.50000 -4.5455 -6.5217 -4.0282

Answer (score 0):

1. Format each cell range you want to use as the source data for the
   chart, I would recommend formatting as Excel tables via CTRL+T on the keyboard.
2. Rename each table. Use Table Design Ribbon > Name where you can change the table names away from defaults of Table1, Table2, ...
3. In VBA, reference or loop through each of the tables in the workbook, they are ListObjects according to the excel VBA reference.

   ```
   Dim ListObj As Excel.ListObject
   Dim ws As worksheet

   For Each ListObj In ws.ListObjects
       ' make a chart
   Next ListObj
   ```

Other methods can work based around how you format/set up/refer to the range with your data.

You could make your own named ranges to refer to the tables, Table1:"A1:Z4" etc. then refer to those in the code or make a list of their addresses ("A1:Z4") ("AA1:AZ4") to include in the VBA, etc.  These may work but offer less flexibility compared to formatting data as excel tables.

Comment: Hi, I tried doing this method but it is not working. this is the code I am using:

Comment: i am trying the following after I create the list objects, but getting error                                       

Sub charts()

Dim ListObj As Excel.ListObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As ListObject
Dim cht As ChartObject

For Each ListObj In ws.ListObjects
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Top:=200, _
        Width:=400, Height:=300)
         'Determine the chart type
    cht.Chart.ChartType = xlLine       
Next ListObj

End Sub